# java polymorphism not working, what am I missing?

Tags: java, dynamic, methods, polymorphism

I have the following hierarchy in my project:

```
public abstract class AbstractMessage extends AbstractEntity{}
public class ParseFailedMessage extends AbstractMessage {}
public class SubParsedFailedMessage extends ParseFailedMessage {}
```

I have the following methods:

```
public AbstractMessage doHandle(AbstractMessage messageToHandle) {

   //prepareToHandle(messageToHandle);

   handle(messageToHandle);

   //finalize(messageToHandle);

   return messageToHandle;

}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
private void handle(ParseFailedMessage message) {

   message.setHandled(false);

}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
private void handle(AbstractMessage message) {

   message.setHandled(true);

}
```

For some reason when I call the doHandle(new SubParsedFailedMessage())
the function that being called from it is handle(AbstractMessage msg) and not 
handle(SubParsedFailedMessage msg) as *emphasized text* was expecting..

Can anyone say why polymorphism is not working here?

Comment: `ParseFailedMessage ` is `AbstractMessage`, But `AbstractMessage` is NOT `ParseFailedMessage`.

Comment: but isn't there a dynamic method invocation??

Comment: Yes, there is but the *runtime* type of AbstractMessage is either *ParseFailedMessage* or itself, so e it won't fail at runtime. But other method  `handle(ParseFailedMessage)` only accepts *ParseFaildMessage* type else it will fail at runtime.

Comment: So how can i overcome this? without implementing .handle() in my messages classes? (if possible)

Answer (score 2):

doHandle is declared to receive a parameter of type AbstractMessage. This means that when your code is compiled, the code generated for the call to handle() is generated to call handle(AbstractMessage), rather than handle(ParseFailedMessage).

If you still want a function to be called according to the dynamic type of the object, you should make that function a member of SubParsedFailedMessage, and call messageToHandle.handle(). This also looks more OOP-like, and is therefore preferred.

Comment: I can't since handle() is a @service method (Service bean) and the messages hierarchy is not bean based, that means i wont be able to do transactions.

Comment: But couldn't you just make doHandle() transactional instead and still do what Eran suggested?

Comment: I think ill make all my messages as beans. then autowire the messagesService for all of them and implement the do handle, i just hoped there is another way

Answer (score 2):

Eran's explanation of the cause of the problem is correct, method overloading is evaluated at compile-time.

After thinking about it for a while I came up with a possible solution.

One solution to this problem is the Visitor design pattern:

You need an interface, call it `MessageHandler` that defines your `handle()` methods.

Put an abstract `dispatch(MessageHandler handler)` method on AbstractMessage and an implementation that is one line of code like so

```
public void dispatch(MessageHandler handler) {
    handler.handle(this)
}
```

in each message. This means the compiler will have the information on where to dispatch the method call at compile time and dispatch correctly. As a refactoring step say `AbstractMessage` implements `MessageHandler`. Later this can be factored out into its own class.

Side benefits:
Your message handling code will be separated from your message definitions and you can replace you message handler with something different for unit tests or for different use cases.

Cons:
The message handler interface needs an abstract `handle()`method for each message type that you want to dispatch this way.